# How to set Safe Area layout for older Apps?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, iphone-x

I just started working on a new project which has been done when Xcode 6 was released. The previous developer has used a View instead of the navigation Bar at the top of a few views. I want to fix the height of the View at the top for the new iPhone X as the navigation view looks very small and is cut by the notch. And as the project was created earlier with Xcode 6 I don't see Safe area, is there anyway I can update my previous XIB's with Safe area without requiring to recreate them all ?

The other option I have is creating a new XIB and optimize it for iPhone X layout and call it when the view is loaded.

Comment: Here is similar reference question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46111811/what-is-safe-area-in-xib-in-xcode-9

Comment: I am not using Story Board in my App, so I just wanted to know how to enable this programmatically for Xib files created before ?

Comment: Here is another reference, if you want solution programatically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075615/objective-c-how-to-create-self-view-inside-safe-area-programmatically